# Did I correctly take action after a review mistake?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I fat-fingered "Looks OK" on a question [which clearly wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14519870). I tried to hit "back" and hope I could give it the correct category, which is "needs editing" if I'm being kind. I couldn't change my vote, so I left a comment admitting fault and recommended a [MCVE]. Was this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Don't worry, other users will probably take the right action (hopefully). Your comment is fine.

Comment: Did you at least flag it for closure?  Commenting about how you got the review wrong is noise at *best*.

Comment: I flagged it, appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Turns out two others had fat fingers too...

Comment: It's closed now, move on, nothing to see here

Comment: @Makoto I don't see any harm in mentioning it if some kind of explanation is given with it. Of course, explaining a close vote is even better; if combined with a close vote, mentioning the fat finger might be helpful if someone reviews the history and sees the contradictory actions.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yep, but in this case, OP doesn't have the magical voting powers you describe.

Comment: @Zizouz212 ...Is it me, or is it odd that a person has triage privileges but not close privileges?

Comment: Triage has "Looks OK", "Requires Editing" and "Unsalvageable - choose a flag". Triage will send things off to other queues I believe. I think what SO wanted was to have decently experiences users to be able to classify questions so that it wouldn't clutter up other queues. To use a hospital example, you wouldn't want a guy with broken bones coming up to the heart centre, you use the triage to tell people where to go.

Comment: Who fat-fingered here and voted to close as *not reproducible*???

Comment: What's with all the fat fingers? Too much waffles?

Comment: If it needs a MCVE and should be closed, then the appropriate triage result is unsalvageable.  Requires editing is only appropriate is a general SO user can do the editing, not the OP.